# MNC and MCC of all the providers

Tags: android, gsm, signal-strength, cellid

I wanted to get a list of all providers which is in the range of cell phone in an android app.

I know that with certain classes like `CellNeigbouringInfo, GSMCellLocation, SignalStrength` and `PhoneStateListener` ,

I am able to get `CellID, MNC and signal strengths` of *only those with which I am currently connected to but if I want to get details of all the providers in that area, How would I be able to get it?

Comment: sorry for bad English initially i posted the question in hurry. Would anyone help me?